# React-PDF Css Styles not applying on file download

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blob, react-pdf, tiptap

I am working on exporting tiptap html strings into formatted and styled multipage pdfs. All of the text content is properly displaying in the document across the multiple pages, but no css styles are working. I cannot add margins or change the background color of the pdf document. I attached my code for creating the pdf content as well as two methods I have tried for downloading the content.

```
import { Document, Page, View, Text } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

export type EditablePDFContentProps = {
    html: string
}

const EditablePDFContent = (props: EditablePDFContentProps) => {
    const lines = props.html.split('<p></p>') // Split HTML content by <br> tag
    const lineHeight = 16 // Line height in pixels
    const pageHeight = 800 // Maximum page height in pixels
    const maxLinesPerPage = Math.floor(pageHeight / lineHeight) // Maximum number of lines per page based on the page height and line height

    // Create an array of pages based on the length of the content
    const pages = []
    let currentPage: JSX.Element[] = []
    let currentPageHeight = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const line: string = lines[i]
        const lineHeightPixel = Math.ceil(line.length / 50) * lineHeight // Calculate the height of the line based on the line length
        const remainingPageHeight = pageHeight - currentPageHeight

        if (lineHeightPixel > remainingPageHeight) {
            // Create a new page if the line doesn't fit on the current page
            pages.push(
                <Page size="A4" key={`page-${i}`} style={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}>
                    <View style={{ margin: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}>{currentPage}</View>
                </Page>
            )
            currentPage = [<Text key={`line-${i}`}>{line}</Text>]
            currentPageHeight = lineHeight
        } else {
            // Add the line to the current page if it fits
            currentPage.push(<Text key={`line-${i}`}>{line}</Text>)
            currentPageHeight += lineHeight
        }
    }

    // Add the last page
    pages.push(
        <Page size="A4" key={`page-${lines.length}`}>
            <View>{currentPage}</View>
        </Page>
    )

    return (
        <>
            <Document>{pages}</Document>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditablePDFContent
```

Exporting pdf as a blob:

```
async function exportToPdf() {
        const blobPdf = await pdf(<EditablePDFContent html={content} />).toBlob()
        saveAs(blobPdf, 'test.pdf')
    }
```

Exporting pdf using react-pdf PDFDownloadLink

```
<PDFDownloadLink document={<EditablePDFContent html={content} />} fileName="somename.pdf">
                                {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
                            </PDFDownloadLink>
```

Any help is appreciated!